# Is there an "Explain Query" for MongoDB Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, query-optimization, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a way to run `.explain()` or equivalent on Linq queries? I would want to know

- The text of the actual JSON query
- The output of `.explain()` (indexes used, etc)
- It would also be nice to have the execution time of the query

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the Json easily enough if you have a query wrapper;

```
var qLinq = Query<T>.Where(x => x.name=="jim");
Console.WriteLine(qLinq.ToJson());
```

There's also an Explain() method on MongoCursor, so you could do this;

```
var exp = Collection.FindAs<T>(qLinq).Explain()
Console.WriteLine(exp.ToJson());
```

So if you want the time taken, "millis" is in there;

```
var msTaken = exp.First(x => x.Name == "millis").Value.AsInt32;
```

If you have an `IQueryable`, try something like this;

```
void Do(MongoCollection col, IQueryable iq)
{
        // Json Mongo Query
        var imq = (iq as MongoQueryable<Blob>).GetMongoQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(imq.ToString());

        // you could also just do;
        // var cursor = col.FindAs(typeof(Blob), imq);
        var cursor = MongoCursor.Create(typeof(Blob), col, imq, ReadPreference.Nearest);
        var explainDoc = cursor.Explain();

        Console.WriteLine(explainDoc);
    }//Do()
```

Comment: Thanks. Most of our queries are from `IQueryable` objects. Maybe the better question is how to turn an `IQueryable` into an `IMongoQuery`?

Comment: That's not so easy to go in that direction, but you can do it - see updated answer. The other approach is to put a Repository over the Mongo Linq layer so that you can work with Query<> objects directly, do your logging then return IQueryable rather than try and convert IQueryable to Query<>

Comment: thanks for the help. Your solution doesn't actually compile though. See my updates for what actually works for me (note how I have to rip deep into the `Expression` to get the `where` clause).

Comment: Sorry, I was writing blind. In any case, I think it's a lot easier than this. The Expression is probably a red-herring we really want a MongoCursor, see above.

Comment: The latest version of the Driver has an "Explain" extension method for IQueryable.

Comment: @cirrus It's probably time to just delete all that strike-through text from your answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you want this functionality in a library, I just created a GitHub project entitled

**MongoDB query helper for .NET**

https://github.com/mikeckennedy/mongodb-query-helper-for-dotnet

It will:

- Explain a LINQ query **as a strongly typed object** (does it use an index for example)
- Convert a LINQ query to the JavaScript code run in MongoDB

Check it out and contribute if you find it interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. It shows everything `.explain` does and has a boolean for verbosity (it includes the time it took to execute):

```
var database = new MongoClient().GetServer().GetDatabase("db");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Hamster>("Hamsters");

var explanation = collection.AsQueryable().Where(hamster => hamster.Name == "bar").Explain(true);
Console.WriteLine(explanation);
```

It doesn't show the query though. Here's an extension method for that:

```
public static string GetMongoQuery<TItem>(this IQueryable<TItem> query)
{
    var mongoQuery = query as MongoQueryable<TItem>;
    return mongoQuery == null ? null : mongoQuery.GetMongoQuery().ToString();
}
```

Usage:

```
var query = collection.AsQueryable().Where(hamster => hamster.Name == "bar").GetMongoQuery();
Console.WriteLine(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

In mongodb 3 C# I used following:

```
var users = Mongo.db.GetCollection<User>("Users");
var r = users(m => m._id == yourIdHere)
    .Project(m => new { m._id, m.UserName, m.FirstName, m.LastName })
    .Limit(1);

Console.WriteLine(r.ToString());
```

**Result:**

```
find({ "_id" : ObjectId("56030e87ca42192008ed0955") }, { "_id" : 1, "UserName" : 1, "FirstName" : 1, "LastName" : 1 }).limit(1)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be `r.ToString()` instead? I'm confused as to how the above code can produce the result you've specified.

Comment: You are right. I corrected code example. It should be r.ToString() instead of users.ToString()