# MongoDb c# driver 2.0 query styles

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Early we used a `LINQ` provider for `MongoDb`, but now we have migrated to `MongoDb c# driver 2.0` and there are a few things that i don't understand.

When we used a `LINQ` provider the query was like the following:

```
  var query = from c in dbCollection.AsQueryable()
                        where c.UserId == userId && c.CampaignId == campaignId
                        select c;
```

But right now i can implement it in a few ways:

```
var query =
     Builders<Analytics>.Filter.Eq(a => a.UserId, userId) &
     Builders<Analytics>.Filter.Eq(a => a.CampaignId, campaignId);
```

and

```
Builders<Analytics>.Filter.Where(
c => c.created >= Convert.ToDateTime(dateFrom) &&
     c.created <= Convert.ToDateTime(dateTo));
```

Is there are any differences or advantages in these approaches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MongoDB tutorial I was doing once, they stated that you can always use LINQ, but you should not force it.
This is simply because not everything was implemented in LINQ already and probably is not (or is not even possible) to implement via the LINQ "way".
It actually means you can use both way. You can use either the Fluent API or the LINQ where possible.

Comment: So there are no difference between using Where with some predicate and Eq,Ne,etc builder's methods ?

Comment: Actually my answer was only partial about the comparision between the LINQ and the other two styles. I would at least expect that this should convert all into the "driver communication". I guess there must be a way somehow to verify this by some server statistics or any other approach. There must be a way to verify what the driver really does (Probably in the JavaScript notation used in the Shell)

Comment: If I add --verbose as command line parameter for my mongo server instance I can see some part of the query. So you could just try the two and check if the two approaches cause a different behaviour.

Comment: Probably the explain functionality would be also helpful to check this. See this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254784/is-there-an-explain-query-for-mongodb-linq