# MongoDB - can't use .explain() to get query info in C# code?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using **Mongo 2.2**. How can I access the query info using C#?

Currently have the following to get my data:

```
 var records = _collection.Find(filters).ToList<Vehicle>();
```

I was trying to add a .explain() similarily to what I can do in Robomongo at the end of my query:

```
var records = _collection.Find(filters).explain();
```

However, it does not exist, I believe because its not a cursor. Does anyone know how I can get this query data in C#?

Comment: You want `explain` result data in C#?

Comment: Yes, exactly, explain result data.

Comment: which mongo driver are you using fro C#? and why you want this result in C# as this info is only about query statistics

Comment: Drivers: MongoDb.Bsonv(2.2.4), MongoDb.Driver(v2.2.4), MongoDb.Driver.Core(v2.2.4) - I need it as we want to see exactly what query is executed in the Application.

Answer (score 0):

There is .Explain() method of MongoCursor class resulting from FindAs() method of MongoCollection class. I found an answer from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254784/is-there-an-explain-query-for-mongodb-linq).

```
var qLinq = Query<T>.Where(x => x.name=="jim");

var exp = Collection.FindAs<T>(qLinq).Explain()
```