# How do I run an explain query with the 2.4 C# Mongo driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

A long time ago using an older version of the Mongo C# driver, it was possible to do something along the lines of this (I forget exactly).

```
collection.FindOne(query).Explain()
```

And this would provide details of query execution, indexes used, etc. using [cursor.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/). Now we're using 2.4 and would like to use explain for one of our queries.

The only question I found relating to this was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742956/mongodb-cant-use-explain-to-get-query-info-in-c-sharp-code) but the driver used seems to be different again.

How do I run an explain query with the 2.4 C# driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to an [issue on MongoDB's JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1250) page, it was removed from the API as an out of the box feature.

> Explain is/has undergone some changes and adding it to the driver before that is done would have been a mistake. In addition, we feel that most explanations happen in the shell and not in the drivers. As a result, we've not included explain as part of the API.

Fortunately, it's still possible by supplying the query modifier in `FindOptions`:

```
var options = new FindOptions
{
    Modifiers = new BsonDocument("$explain", true)
};
var explain = await collection.Find(x => true, options)
    .Project(new BsonDocument())
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ?.ToJson();
```

Simply replace `x => true` with the query you would like to profile. I've added `.ToJson()` in order to get a nice human-readable JSON string.

Comment: If I simply add Modifiers in FindOptions, it works. But since my indexes are case insensitive and are using collation, I am using this -----

    query = collection.Find(filter, options: new FindOptions {
                    Collation = request.SearchCollation,
                    Modifiers = new BsonDocument("$explain", true)
                }).SortByDescending(x => x._Id).Limit(request.Limit);

                var explain = query.Project(new BsonDocument()).FirstOrDefault()?.ToJson();
 
It is giving an exception that OP_QUERY does not support collations.

Comment: @shanti Are you saying that Collation on its own works, and Modifiers on its own works, but together they produce an error?

Comment: yeah, this is what happened with me.

Comment: @shanti Hmm. I'm not sure, I'm afraid. You might have to post a new question about it.

Comment: It loos like that in the latest version of the driver FindOptions.Modifiers is not marked as obsolete.