# Why is the MongoDB query not returning any results? (Filtering by cutoff date)

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Here is the C# query I have:

```
public Task<UserStats> GetStatsForUserWithId(string userId, DateTime? cutoffDate = null)
{
    var idFilter = Builders<UserStats>.Filter.Eq(s => s.UserId, userId);
    var cutoffDateFilter = Builders<UserStats>.Filter.Lt(s => s.Timestamp, cutoffDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue);

    return _stats
        .Find(idFilter & cutoffDateFilter)
        .SortByDescending(stats => stats.Timestamp)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Here is the equivalent MongoDB query I'm trying to replicate - this works:

```
db.getCollection('stats').find({
    "UserId": "5ca13b15d74d5633c45a3304",
    "Timestamp": { $lt: ISODate("2022-04-01T02:17:04+0000") }
}).sort({ 
    "Timestamp": -1 
}).limit(1)
```

Here is the entity being stored, in case it matters:

```
public class UserStats
{ 
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public Stats1V1 Stats1V1 { get; set; }
    public Stats2V2 Stats2V2 { get; set; }
    public StatsOverall StatsOverall { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

The problem: When I run the C# query, I get no results. The MongoDB query works fine, suggesting there is some difference between the two that I'm not seeing. What is it?

Here's a sample object of what is stored in the DB, with the non-relevant fields omitted to keep things short:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca167ac8c7e7250843553a4"),
    "UserId" : "5ca13b15d74d5633c45a3304",
    "Stats1V1" : {
        // omitted a bunch of fields
    },
    "Stats2V2" : {
        // omitted a bunch of fields
    },
    "StatsOverall" : {
        // omitted a bunch of fields
    },
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2019-04-01T01:21:48.861Z")
}
```

EDIT: I should point out that the query worked perfectly before the cutoff date filter was added. The sorting, Id filter, etc. worked before, everything stopped working when I added the new cutoff date filter.

Comment: Can you run an explain as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506857/how-do-i-run-an-explain-query-with-the-2-4-c-sharp-mongo-driver/49506858#49506858). The explain should include the query you executed for the C# part. Can you add that to your question?

Comment: Sore, and I'll post an actual instance of the data in the database to help as well, so you can see if the datatypes match up or whatnot.

Comment: I don't think this is what you want: `{ \"_t\" : \"AsyncStateMachineBox`1\", \"_id\" : 68, \"StateMachine\" : { \"<>1__state\" : -2, \"<>t__builder\" : { }, \"source\" : { \"_t\" : \"FindFluent`2\", \"Filter\" : { \"_t\" : \"AndFilterDefinition`1\" } }, \"cancellationToken\" : { } }, \"Context\" : { } }`

Comment: But that's what I get from attempting to run an explain with the solution in that question

Comment: I've been playing with the code you linked, but haven't gotten anywhere with it. It's now giving me: `{"Element 'queryPlanner' does not match any field or property of class DataAccess.Entities.Stats.UserStats."}`

Comment: it seams to me the issue is about the id , try [BsonId] public ObjectId Id { get; set; } instead, in your UserStats class

Comment: It's not shown in the example so are you definitely remembering to `await` the call to `GetStatsForUserWithId`?

Comment: @GregStanley Yes, I'm awaiting it in the calling function.

Comment: @Ali Do you have an explanation for this? I'm using the BsonId for a reason, and it would probably cause regressions to change this. It could be done, but I'd rather understand the problem.

Comment: @Bassinator when you use string as your id type and [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] decoration, Mongo driver needs to convert your string type to the ObjectId type and i think something is going wrong there , the safest way is to use ObjectId type instead of string in your TDocument class , [BsonId] decoration is to make sure mongo is aware of the _id property since the name may not be _id , id , ID in your TDocument class

Comment: @Bassinator FWIW I ran something I would consider to be logically the same on my machine yeterday and it appeared to work - I got results using both filters - so you can't be far off. Apologies if I'm stating the obvious given your update I'd go straight to checking the format of the dates themselves and try doing some more basic queries using that field alone.

Answer (score 1):

So, I solved the problem with the help from a coworker.

It turns out it was actually caused by the way C# Web API controller methods handle query parameters that are not specified. I had assumed (being new to .NET) that like any function parameter in C# that isn't provided, it defaults to null. However, for query parameters, this is apparently not the case - it assumes a default value of the beginning of our calendar.

I was coalescing null values into some reasonable date in the future, but this operation would never execute because the variable was never actually null.

I should have discovered this when I stepped through it in the debugger, but I apparently missed it somehow, not sure how.

However, I wanted to share the information that helped me discover the cause of the problem - I used the profiling tools built into MongoDB to track down the cause.

By running the following lines in the MongoDB shell:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(0)
db.system.profile.drop()
db.createCollection( "system.profile", { capped: true, size:4000000 } )
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

to enable profiling, running my API call, and then running the following line in the Mongo shell:

```
db.system.profile.find().pretty()
```

I was able to receive this output (shortened to the important part):

```
    "command" : {
        "find" : "stats",
        "filter" : {
            "Timestamp" : {
                "$lt" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z")
            }

// omitted
```

Notice that the timestamp here is in the year 0001. That lead to me investigating how it got that value, which was eventually revealed by the debugger.

Hopefully this approach can help someone else in the future.