# C# MongoDB IAsyncCursor Explain

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-.net-driver

I am currently having a text index in my data. I am performing a regex search and I want to make sure that the correct index is used. In the mongo shell I just used **explain** but how could I use **explain** in the C# driver?

Here's how I perform my query:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<GridFSFileInfo>> Find(string fileName)
    {
        var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Regex(x => x.Filename, $"/.*{fileName}.*/i");
        var options = new FindOptions
        {
            Modifiers = new BsonDocument("$hint", "filename_text")
        };
        var result = new List<GridFSFileInfo>();

        using (var cursor = await Collection.Find(filter, options).ToCursorAsync())
        {
            while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                var batch = cursor.Current;
                result.AddRange(batch);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Is there something like **Collection.Find(filter, options).Explain()** that returns a string or something? I searched on the web and found this: [Is there an "Explain Query" for MongoDB Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254784/is-there-an-explain-query-for-mongodb-linq) However is seems there is no Explain method...

Comment: Do you have any update on this? After learning what Explain() is from MongoDB Documentation, I tried to look for it in C#. But could not find it...

Comment: @shanti nope, still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The modern mongo c# drivers support only one way to configure `$explain`. You can do it via `FindOptions.Modifiers` in the same was as you configured `$hint` above.

```
        var options = new FindOptions
        {
            Modifiers = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "$hint", "filename_text" },
                { "$explain", 1 }
            }
        };

        var cursor = coll.Find(filter, options).As<BsonDocument>().ToCursor();
```

Pay attention, since `$explain` completely changes the server response, you should change your output type to `BsonDocument`(or a type with fields that matches to what explain returns) via `As` (if it's already not `BsonDocument`)