# MongoDb & C# : Using a Cursor with a sort on a large Index

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

So I would like to de-dup my dataset which has **2 billion records** in.  I have an index on url, and I want to iterate through each record and see if it's a duplicate.

**The index is 110GB**

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command find failed: Executor
>   error during find command :: caused by :: Sort operation used more
>   than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a
>   smaller limit..'

My current method won't run because of the Index being huge.

```
var filter = Builders<Page>.Filter.Empty;
var sort = Builders<Page>.Sort.Ascending("url");
await collection.Find(filter).Sort(sort)
    .ForEachAsync(async document =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(document.Url);
        //_ = await collection.DeleteOneAsync(a => a.Id == document.Id);
    }
);
```

Comment: If there is already an index on `{url:1}` it should be using the index instead of an in-memory sort.  You might try database profiling to see what query is actually be sent to the server.

Comment: Are you saying it should use Url instead of the default ID one?

Comment: The 32 MB memory limit for sort doesn't apply when an index is used for sorting.

Comment: So how do I do that so I can iterate through the documents

Comment: Try using [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254784/is-there-an-explain-query-for-mongodb-linq) with the all plans execution option, or perhaps database profiling, to see why it isn't using the `{url:1}` index.

Comment: So are you saying when you add an index to a mongo table it then uses that first index by default and not the ID?

Comment: The query planner will evaluate all of the index that are relevant to the query to determine which one performs the best.  `explain` lets you see what the planner chose, and if you use the allPlansExecution option, you can see comparative performance of the various choices.

Answer (score 1):

if the goal is to delete duplicate pages with the same url, why not use an aggregation like the following:

```java
db.Page.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $sort: {
                url: 1
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$url",
                doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
            }
        },
        {
            $replaceWith: "$doc"
        },
        {
            $out: "UniquePages"
        }
    ],
    {
        allowDiskUse: 1
    })
```

it will create a new collection called `UniquePages`. after inspecting that collection to see if the data is correct, you can simply drop the old `Page` collection and rename the new one to `Page`.

Comment: @Burf2000 i suppose you don't have 9TB of free disk space? :-)

Comment: Sadly not mate, I will give it a try though but 2 TB short

Answer (score -1):

- Make sure that sort operation uses an index. This will mostly perform better and memory sort h**as a restriction on a maximum of 32MB**. [Refer
  to doc.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/index.html#operations) and check doc [uses indexes to sort query results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/).
- Use [query plan](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/) to identify the selected / winningPlan execution plan
- Analyse query performance details with [executionStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/)

Comment: Not sure this answers the actual question>  I am using an index that's 110GB

Comment: This is to diagnose and analyse the reported error.